# Local window shows empty Variables while debugging SSIS package in VS Data tools 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, visual-studio-debugging, sql-server-2012-datatools

This has been bothering me for a long time.  I am unable to debug SSIS package efficiently because the **Variables** collection of SSIS package is always empty.

SS of Locals window showing blank value for `Variables` collection variable

[image: After expanding variables node]

***Updated*** after userfl89 gave an alternative solution
Also, the watch window is showing *unable to evaluate the expression* error message

[image]

I found a similar issue in general VS development environments (C#, VB.NET) and tried suggestions/answers. For example, changing Debug->Options->Debugging-> check Managed c++ compatibility mode (see ss below) but it did not work for me.

SS of debugging setting:

I have also tried to run in both 64bit mode and 32bit mode, but this also did not work. However, I can see variable values inside script task written in C# code. It has become a painful task to debug packages. Please someone help.
[image: Debugging settings]

Environment: 
Windows 7 Enterprise (64bit)
Visual studio 2012 for Data Tools (version 11.0.6xxx)
.Net Framework 4.6

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you already set a breakpoint?  When the package hits the breakpoint, on the top menu go to `Debug > Windows > Locals` and from here expand the top variables node, however it looks like you've already done this.  You can also view the variables values in the Watch windows by typing the name of the variable in the `Name` field when the breakpoint is reached.  This will only be the variable name, not the `@[User::Variable]` syntax.

Comment: This is alternative solution not actual solution. The main issue is the collection variable is always blank. Anyway, thanks for useful tip for not to use SSIS variable syntax in watch window.